# Extract a particular string given its heading - regex

Tags: python-3.x

Am trying to extract a particular string in the below data.
I have to extract the observations mentioned in the data. There are various ways observations has been written, for ex : OBSERVATION, Observation, observed, OBSERVED ....

Please let me know how to extract this.

Data :
Preconditions :1)One valid navigation map should be installed on the MGU.2)One route must be active.\nActions/steps : 1)Press PTT button.\n2)Give voice command "Navigate to Alibaba Restaurant" and observe system\' s behavior.\n\nExpected result/behaviour:\n1) Confirmation prompt of given spoken command should be played.  \n2)User shall get the list of POI\'s which are spoken by user for e.g. \n\n\nObserved result/behavior:\n1) Confirmation prompt of given spoken command is not played.\n2) User not able to select POI via speech commands.\n3)User getting the list of POI destination but user not able to select those point via spoken commands for e.g.

Comment: In the above one, its good if we can partition every heading, like 'condition:', 'Observed:' , 'expected:' into multiple columns ..

Comment: can you add expected output here, from given input for more visibility...

Comment: sure @Vikram Singh .. This is the expected output.  The ouput should be of ...""OBSERVED : Confirmation prompt of given spoken command is not played""